# Why do I get the exception: Could not load type 'xy' from assembly 'System.Xaml'?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, installation

I have a WPF application with the .Net 4 client profile framework. When I installed it on a new Windows XP machine, with the .NET 4 Client profile installed. I have this error message on lunching the app.

> Could not load type 'System.Windows.Markup.ValueSerializerAttribute'
>   from assembly 'System.Xaml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

I checked for the *System.Xaml.dll*, it's there in :

> C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319

Any ideas ? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT :**

I found this information on the [msdn website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.valueserializerattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) :

> **Platforms** :
>        Windows 7, Windows Vista SP1 or later, Windows XP SP3, Windows Server 2008 (Server Core not supported), Windows Server 2008 R2 (Ser
>   ver Core supported with SP1 or later), Windows Server 2003 SP2

Comment: why do you use the Client profile?

Comment: @Venson : Bacause I do not need the Full, but I tryed and installed the full on the XP machine, didn't work

Comment: Do you using DevExpress or any 3th party libs?

Comment: Which IDE (Visual Studio/DevExpress) are you using?

Comment: Is it built for x64?  Did you check C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64 ?

Comment: @Venson : Yes, I'm using DevExpress 12.1.5

Comment: @matt-dot-net no th target is set to x86

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved when I did an update of DevExpress from 12.2.4 to 13.1.4. Don't know why exactly, but it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are properly missing the [VisualStudio C++ Runtimes](http://www.microsoft.com/de-de/download/details.aspx?id=5555).
This is a big problem with DevExpress so you may got another exception:

`FileNotFoundExeption` that is "normal" on new PCs and DevExpress

Comment: Ok, I'll check it tomorrow, once in the office, and informe you about the result, thanks

Comment: Hello again, I did find the Visual C++ Redistributable x86 installed on the XP machine (it is defined in the setup prerequisite), I tryed to reinstall it, but I have the same error message.

Comment: I deleted the System.XAML.dll from the C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 directory, but I still have the same error message (I expected "System.XAML.dll not found").

Comment: Try to extract DevExpress from your project and try it again without it for testing

Comment: How can I extract DevExpress from my project ? If I do so, the solution does not built at all.  I updated my DevExpress version to 12.2.6. Not working !

Comment: I guess there is a Tool from DevExpress for that, but im not sure. Do it manually: Remove all your Refferences and than replace all your XAML code